# How to get the full width at half maximum (FWHM) from kdeplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, kdeplot

I have used seaborn's kdeplot on some data.

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
sns.kdeplot(np.random.rand(100))
```

Is it possible to return the fwhm from the curve created?
And if not, is there another way to calculate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract the generated kde curve from the ax. Then get the maximum y value and search the x positions nearest to the half max:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = sns.kdeplot(np.random.rand(100))
kde_curve = ax.lines[0]
x = kde_curve.get_xdata()
y = kde_curve.get_ydata()
halfmax = y.max() / 2
maxpos = y.argmax()
leftpos = (np.abs(y[:maxpos] - halfmax)).argmin()
rightpos = (np.abs(y[maxpos:] - halfmax)).argmin() + maxpos
fullwidthathalfmax = x[rightpos] - x[leftpos]
ax.hlines(halfmax, x[leftpos], x[rightpos], color='crimson', ls=':')
ax.text(x[maxpos], halfmax, f'{fullwidthathalfmax:.3f}\n', color='crimson', ha='center', va='center')
ax.set_ylim(ymin=0)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Note that you can also calculate a kde curve from [scipy.stats.gaussian_kde](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html) if you don't need the plotted version. In that case, the code could look like:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

data = np.random.rand(100)
kde = gaussian_kde(data)
x = np.linspace(data.min(), data.max(), 1000)
y = kde(x)
halfmax = y.max() / 2
maxpos = y.argmax()
leftpos = (np.abs(y[:maxpos] - halfmax)).argmin()
rightpos = (np.abs(y[maxpos:] - halfmax)).argmin() + maxpos
fullwidthathalfmax = x[rightpos] - x[leftpos]
print(fullwidthathalfmax)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a way to return the fwhm from the random dataplot without writing the code to calculate it.

Take into account some example data:

```
import numpy as np

arr_x = np.linspace(norm.ppf(0.00001), norm.ppf(0.99999), 10000)
arr_y = norm.pdf(arr_x)
```

Find the minimum and maximum points and calculate difference.

```
difference = max(arr_y) - min(arr_y)
```

Find the half max (in this case it is half min)

```
HM = difference / 2
```

Find the nearest data point to HM:

```
nearest = (np.abs(arr_y - HM)).argmin()
```

Calculate the distance between nearest and min to get the HWHM, then mult by 2 to get the FWHM.